# Extract Specific column with particular value in R

Tags: r

I have a problem. I have a data frame structured like this

```
 X  a   b   c   d  
 g 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.2  
 h 0.3 0.8  0  0.4
```

i want to create a new matrix, with all the rows of my db and with columns with a value major than 0.5, like this

```
 X   b   c 
 g   /  0.6
 h  0.8  /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a logical matrix (`df1[-1] > 0.5`), get the `colSums`, check whether it is greater than 0, subset the dataset based on the logical `vector`

```
df2 <- df1[c(TRUE, colSums(df1[-1] > 0.5)>0)]
```

and assign the values <= 0.5 to NA

```
df2[-1][df2[-1] <= 0.5] <- NA
```

Comment: there is a problem. Error in `[.data.frame`(tab, c(TRUE, colSums(tab[-1] > 50) > 0)) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: @Silvia  It was based on the example you showed and it is working for me